# Como chamar uma função no javascript através de uma caixa de texto?

Tags: javascript

Queria saber como posso chamar uma função por meio de uma caixa de texto. exemplo:

```
<input type="text" value="load()"/>
```

Mas não é exatamente a função load, eu queria que o digitador pudesse chamar qualquer função mesmo.

Comment: A sua pergunta está pouco clara. Quer que o utilizador escreva código no input para ser corrido? ou uma função que corra quando o utilizador escreve texto no input?

Comment: código no input para ser corrido :)

Comment: Você gera o código através de alguma linguagem? caso sim poste aqui, pois talvez seja mais prático inserir o `value` através dela...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar o [**eval()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval).
Experimente assim:

```
var input = document.querySelector('input[type=text]');
input.addEventListener('blur', function(){
    eval(this.value);
});
```

Porém recomendo fortemente a [**ler isto sobre o eval**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4154/uso-do-eval-em-javascript-quais-os-pros-e-contras)();

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/326EU/)

Comment: +1 Sua ideia é muito melhor que a minha... nem me veio à mente =)

Comment: Nossa, funcionou \o/ (nunca ia pensar em usar a função eval). Mas é garantido que funciona mesmo com qualquer função mesmo? Tipo $('#content').html('dddddddd')

Comment: @IagoBruno, sim. Teste este: __http://jsfiddle.net/326EU/2/__

Comment: Se não me engado, "seTimeout" também pode fazer a mesma coisa do eval =p

Comment: Se não for pedir muito, teria algum jeito de detectar se o texto escrito dentro de um input é algo javascript?

Comment: @IagoBruno, isso parece difícil :/ Acho que daria uma boa nova pergunta! Uma ideia (com muitas excepções) é __[testar se tem parenteses assim (link)](http://jsfiddle.net/326EU/3/)__: `input.value.match(/\(?(.*)\)/);`

Comment: Nos meus testes funcionou seu método, mas você acha que pode dar erro em algum caso? Pq ví que ele checa se tem parenteses no value..

Comment: @IagoBruno, um caso onde falha é por exemplo: _"Eu sou o Sérgio (irmão do João)"_

Answer (score 2):

Todos os objetos definidos via código direto na raiz do escopo vão parar no objeto `window`, e portanto você pode fazer assim:

```
window["nome do método"]();
```

Assim vai chamar a função que você quer pelo nome.

Answer (score 0):

Basta utilizar os atributos do tipo `onevent` da tag `input`.

Por exemplo:

```
<input type="text" onkeydown="alert('keydown')" />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MdX76/