# Quais são as formas de aplicar eval no Javascript

Tags: javascript, eval

Existe mais de uma maneira de fazer um `eval()` no javascript, problema é que ele pode ser um perigo para o usuário se mal utilizado.

Internamente alguns outros métodos também fazem eval, por exemplo o `setTimeout()` que se colocado no argumento do `callback` uma string ele vai aplicar um eval.

**Quais são as formas de aplicar eval no Javascript?**

> Complementar ao assunto, achei esta pergunta que visa as [implicações
>   do uso do eval](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4154/uso-do-eval-em-javascript-quais-os-pros-e-contras/4164#4164).

Comment: Pode refrasear / explicar melhor _"Quais são as formas de aplicar eval no Javascript?"_. Refere-se a como o javascript funciona internamente, se existem outros métodos que usam o eval internamente, ou que práticas se devem ter em conta?

Comment: @Sergio me refiro as formas de aplicar o eval focado em quem está criando um código, onde este pode executar um eval, então estou tentando me referir aos métodos que executam em seus argumentos evaluação de código. Mas as outras duas perguntas são interessantes também, como funciona internamente e quais as praticas se devem ter em conta, vou ver se ninguém já as fez antes e se não, vou coloca-las em separado, pois são bem diferentes as questões.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Vou mostrar **oito tipos diferentes** que transformam strings em um código que pode ser executado imediatamente. Neste caso, estou usando **apenas** javascript puro, porém bibliotecas como jQuery tem métodos que implicitamente podem ser exploradas como eval.

### eval()

O proprio [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)

```
eval("alert('lorem ipsum')");
```

### setTimeout()

[setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout) é o mais conhecido exemplo de uso de `eval` caso você passe uma string.

```
// Ambos são equivalentes
setTimeout("alert('lorem ipsum')", 100);
setTimeout(function(){ eval("alert('lorem ipsum')"); }, 100);
```

### setInterval()

[setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval) é semelhante ao setTimeout, porém executa a cada período de tempo e não apenas ao final do tempo escolhido.

```
// Ambos são equivalentes
setInterval("alert('lorem ipsum')", 100);
setInterval(function(){ eval("alert('lorem ipsum')"); }, 100);
```

### new Function()

[Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) implicitamente pode ser considerado uma forma de eval porque ele *aceita strings*

```
var adder = new Function("a", "b", "return a + b");
alert(adder(3,5));
```

### document.write()

[document.write](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write), se usado para escrever tags `<script>`, também funciona como `eval`

```
document.write('<script>alert("lorem ipsum")</script>')
```

### document.writeln()

[document.writeln](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.writeln) é muito parecido com o document.write, porém adiciona uma nova linha ao final.

```
document.writeln('<script>alert("lorem ipsum")</script>')
```

### Data URI

[Data URIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/data_URIs) são o exemplo mais atípico, porém eventualmente são usadas para explorar falhas em navegadores.

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.src = 'data:text/javascript,' + encodeURIComponent('alert("lorem ipsum")')
document.body.appendChild(s);
```

Referência: conhecimento próprio, links da MDN e http://kubyshkin.ru/posts/studying-javascript-eval.html

### DOM

Semelhante à abordagem dos data URIs, mas inserindo o código diretamente em vez de recorrer ao atributo `src`:

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.appendChild(document.createTextNode('alert("lorem ipsum");'));
document.body.appendChild(s);
```

### javascript:

Também semelhante aos data URIs, porém inserindo o código no `location` da página:

```
location.replace('javascript:alert("lorem ipsum");void(0)');
```

Comment: Adicionei links para o Mozilla Developer Network (MDN) para quem quiser pesquisar a fundo a respeito

Comment: +1 complementei a resposta com o setInterval, pois vi nos links do @Emerson

Comment: +1 boa resposta!

Comment: Boa lista! Só chamo atenção para uma diferença importante entre o `eval` mesmo e as demais opções: o código passado ao `eval` roda no escopo em que o `eval` estiver sendo chamado, com acesso a tudo o que estiver disponível nesse escopo; todas as demais opções rodam no escopo global.

Comment: tem também a questão do modo estrito que muda acesso ao escopo e tals...

Comment: Se document.write e data URI são válidos, então certamente usar DOM para criar uma tag <script> com JS de conteúdo também é? O innerHTML funciona neste caso?

Comment: Pessoal, converti a resposta para Wiki da comunidade. Sintam-se livres para editar e acrescentar informação aqui. Creio que assim será melhor pra todos. Só por favor antes de fazer uma alteração significativa, justificar a alteração.

Answer (score 5):

De facto o setTimeout e o setInterval podem usar um método semelhante ao `eval()` no caso de não receberem uma função (anónima ou referenciada) como primeiro parametro.

O desejado, boa prática, seria:

```
// declarar a função antes
function foo(){
   alert('foo');
}
setTimeout(foo,1000);

// usar uma função anónima
setTimeout(function(){
    foo();
},1000);
```

No caso de se passar uma string para estes métodos, por exmplo:

```
setTimeout('alert(foobar)' ,1000);
```

isto [pode ter implicações](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4154/uso-do-eval-em-javascript-quais-os-pros-e-contras) sérias de segurança, **mas também problemas de escopo**. Esta string vai ser avaliada no escopo geral, e se neste caso a variável `foobar` estiver no mesmo escopo do seTimeout mas não no escopo geral, ela não vai ser encontrada.

--

Outra maneira é [inserir novo script](http://jsfiddle.net/XjPsU/) na página em forma de string. Assim usando:

```
var s = document.createElement('script');
s.type = 'text/javascript';
s.text = 'alert("Olá mundo!");';
$(document.body).append(s);
```

Comment: +1 porque além também incluiu implicações de segurança que é complementar a pergunta, obrigado.

Answer (score 3):

Duas outras formas maneiras de exuecutar código Javascript de uma string são o construtor Function

```
var f = new Function('alert("oi")');
f();
```

e criar uma tag `<script>`, como sugerido [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12227566/ways-to-evaluate-a-string):

```
var scrEl = document.createElement('script');
scrEl.innerHTML = "window.alert(1);"
document.body.appendChild(scrEl);
```