# Converter string para objeto em JavaScript sem APIs

Tags: javascript

Eu tenho uma string, pegada por uma função, chamada `package`, e seu valor é equivalente a `"edos.desktop"`.

```
function callMain(package) {
    //queria fazer tipo assim, é apenas uma suposição:
    package.main();
}
```

Como podem ver acima, quero chamar uma função que chame `main()` dentro de cada package digitado.
Aqui vai dois exemplos:

Para cada:

```
callMain("edos.desktop");
```

A função faria:

```
edos.package.main();
```

E queria que fosse independente do *package*. Por exemplo, quero chamar milhares de packages, um diferente do outro, mas todos com pontos (`"."`).

E então para não digitar milhares de vezes:

```
  package.main();
```

Eu criei essa função, que converteria tal string para variável e chamaria a função `main()`.

Resumindo, quero fazer:

```
//(dentro da função callMain())
"edos.package".main(); //quero que isso vire isso:
edos.package.main();
```

Comment: Acho que vou ficar sem resposta, e ainda um voto negativo que nem sei porque...

Comment: A sua pergunta é confusa. Não sei se está bem claro pra ti o que é `string`, objeto e função ainda. Mas, pra te dar uma luz, da uma olhada [nessa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359788/how-to-execute-a-javascript-function-when-i-have-its-name-as-a-string) e também no conceito de [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval). Talvez dê uma luz

Comment: 1- Por favor, não coloque o título todo em maiúsculas e nem tags que não têm relação com a pergunta, isso é só ruído e não faz com que respostas surjam mais rapidamente. 2- É domingo e o site fica mais vazio mesmo, tenha paciência que durante a semana tem mais usuários ativos. 3- Talvez o que vc precise é o [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) - aproveite e leia também [isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4154/112052) e [isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4897/112052) para entender melhor as implicações de usar `eval`

Comment: tinham me explicado o eval de um jeito diferente, pensei que a função tinha que ficar de fora da string.. como eu usei ```eval("objeto.objeto").função();``` ao inves de ```eval("objeto.objeto.função")()```...

Comment: Enfim, eu vou tentar...

Comment: Vc pode passar qualquer código válido dentro do eval, inclusive chamada de funções: https://jsfiddle.net/tbh32da5/

Comment: Cara, não sei se é pq eu uso o javascript original, mas quando eu botei esse ```eval(package + ".main()");``` ele não funcionou, inclusive após esse comando inclui um alert dizendo "funcionou", mas nem o alert rodou...

Comment: Talvez seja o caso de [fazer outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), colocando o código que vc está usando e descrevendo com mais detalhes o problema (lembre-se de fazer um **[mcve]** para que todos possam reproduzir o problema que vc está tendo).

Comment: Tá mas o arquivo que estou tendo o problema tem mais de 200 linhas...

Comment: @hkotsubo , achei o problema, é o eval, eu usei ```setInterval(package + ".main()", 50);``` e funcionou!! Mas o problema agora é outro, o set interval fica repetindo a função ```main()``` toda a hora...

Comment: Então, o link que passei  no comentário anterior (o do **[mcve]**) dá várias dicas para reduzir o código e postar aqui. Fica a dica para as próximas :-)

Comment: Certo, obrigado, mas ainda não entendo porque o eval não funciona, nem o eval nem o Function...

Comment: Ok vou tentar denovo em outro post...