# Como executar uma função javascript de um arquivo json

Tags: javascript, json

Eu tenho um arquivo json que é gerado pelo php e ele é assim:

```
{
     "status":200,
     "command":"faca algo",
      "action":"function (){document.write('quer que eu faÃ§a algo?');}",
      "type":"acao"
}
```

como executar a função que está no arquivo?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tecnicamente, isso não é uma função, pois JSON não comporta funções. É uma string com o código-fonte de uma função dentro. O que você pode fazer para executar é usar o [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) (vale ler o conteúdo do link para entender os perigos associados com isso):

```
var json = '{"status":200,"command":"faca algo","action":"function (){document.write(\'quer que eu faça algo?\'); }","type":"acao"}';
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
// Guarda a função num objeto
var funcao = eval('(' + obj.action + ')');
// Executa a função
funcao();
```

http://jsbin.com/qonesiluyolo/1/edit

Se estiver usando jQuery par obter o JSON, o próprio jQuery já cuida do *parse*:

```
$.getJSON("meuendereco.com/json.json", function (data){
    var funcao = eval('(' + data.action + ')'); 
    // Executa a função 
    funcao();
});
```

Ver também: ***[Uso do eval() em javascript: quais os prós e contras?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4154/uso-do-eval-em-javascript-quais-os-pr%C3%B3s-e-contras)***

Comment: não deu quado eu usei o $.getJSON("meuendereco.com/json.json", function (data){var obj = JSON.parse(data);
// Guarda a função num objeto
var funcao = eval('(' + obj.action + ')');
// Executa a função
funcao();});

Comment: Atualizei a resposta. É que nesse caso não precisa do `JSON.parse`, o jQuery já faz isso pra você.

Comment: Valeu, vaelu mesmo, ficou show.