# Como mostrar a menor idade entre 3 idades com Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Como posso mostrar a menor idade entre 3 idades em javascript?

```
<html>
   <head>
      <title> </title>
        <script type="text/javascript">

        var idade1, idade2, idade3 ;

        idade1 = prompt("Digite a primeira idade");
        idade1 = eval(idade1) ;

        idade2 = prompt("Digite a segunda idade");
        idade2 = eval(idade2) ;

        idade3 = prompt("Digite a terceira idade");
        idade3 = eval(idade3) ;

        if( idade1 < idade2 || idade1 < idade3 );
        document.write( idade1 );
        } 
        else if ( idade2 < idade1 || idade2 < idade3 );
        document.write( idade2 );
        } 
        else 
        {
        ( idade3 < idade1 || idade3 < idade2 );
        document.write( idade3 );}


       </script>

   </head>
  <body> 
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tens alguns erros de sintaxe e outros de semântica:

Quando tens `if( idade1 < idade2 || idade1 < idade3 );` falta um `{`, várias vezes.

Quando tens `||` deves ter `&&` para garantir que é obrigatório e não opcional.

Mudei o `eval` para `Number`. Neste caso faria o mesmo efeito, mas se quem insere o numero colocar código, o `eval` irá correr esse código e pode causar problemas graves de segurança. Ainda que eu defenda o uso do eval, neste caso é errado. Podes [ler mais sobre isso aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/27688/129).

Se queres correr código diferente para cada idade a solução em baixo funciona. Se quiseres saber somente o menor de todos, podes usar o [`Math.min()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/min) como o Cleverson sugeriu [na resposta dele](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/158865/129).

sugestão:

```js
 var idade1, idade2, idade3;

 idade1 = prompt("Digite a primeira idade");
 idade1 = Number(idade1);

 idade2 = prompt("Digite a segunda idade");
 idade2 = Number(idade2);

 idade3 = prompt("Digite a terceira idade");
 idade3 = Number(idade3);

 if (idade1 < idade2 && idade1 < idade3) {
     alert(idade1);
 } else if (idade2 < idade1 && idade2 < idade3) {
     alert(idade2);
 } else {
     (idade3 < idade1 && idade3 < idade2);
     alert(idade3);
 }
```

Comment: ajudou muito, obrigado.

Answer (score 10):

Somente adicionando um detalhe ao exemplo do Sergio, para o que solicitou em vês de comparar via `if else` pode usar uma função do `Javascript` mesmo, o `Math.min() ou Math.max()` minimo e máximo.
Segue exemplo aplicado ao seu modelo:

```
<script>
     var idade1, idade2, idade3;

     idade1 = prompt("Digite a primeira idade");
     idade1 = Number(idade1);

     idade2 = prompt("Digite a segunda idade");
     idade2 = Number(idade2);

     idade3 = prompt("Digite a terceira idade");
     idade3 = Number(idade3);

    var min = Math.min(idade1, idade2, idade3);
    alert(min);

</script>
```

Comment: excelente dica.