# Uso do eval para transformar Razor para Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, razor, eval

Antes de criticar o uso do `eval`, eu li e recomendo [essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/27688/23192).

Leve em consideração o seguinte contexto:

Código C# (Razor):

```
var teste = new
{
    prop1 = 123,
    prop2 = "minha mãe disse 'Háaaaaa!'"
};

var listTeste = new object[2];
listTeste[0] = teste;
```

Agora preciso receber esses dados em uma variável **JavaScript**, como objeto.

**Tentativa 1:**

```
var data1 = @listTeste;
```

> No Visual Studio 2013 o editor mostra erro na linha, já que após o `=`
>   não existe mais JavaScript.

Resultado no HTML interpretado no cliente:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Tentativa 2:**

```
var data2 = '@listTeste';
```

Resultado no HTML interpretado no cliente:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Tentativa 3:**

```
var data3 = '@Json.Encode(listTeste)';
```

Resultado no HTML interpretado no cliente:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Tentativa 4:**

```
var data4 = JSON.parse('@Json.Encode(listTeste)');
```

Resultado no HTML interpretado no cliente:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

> Não entendi muito bem o motivo dessa tentativa não ter dado certo...

---

Eu poderia colocar aqui diversas outras tentativas, mas vamos as que finalmente funcionaram:

**Opção 1:**

```
var data5 = JSON.parse("@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(Json.Encode(listTeste)))");
```

**Opção 2:**

```
var data6 = eval(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(listTeste)));
```

1. Existe alguma outra forma de realizar esse procedimento?
2. Nesse contexto, a **opção 2** me oferece algum risco de segurança?
3. Em termos de desempenho, levando em consideração a alocação de memória e processamento do servidor e do cliente, qual é o mais apropriado?
4. Em relação a clareza e limpeza do código, a **opção 2** seria a mais apropriada?
5. E se meu Javascript estiver um um `.js` separado do `.cshtml`, eu teria que deixar os dados em uma variável global para ter acesso lá?

Comment: Viu esta? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/128845/101

Comment: @Maniero no final de sua resposta você diz:
"O problema do JS é mais embaixo."
Poderia falar sobre isso em uma resposta a essa pergunta, por favor?

Comment: Ih, teria muita coisa pra falar :) E acho que o contexto da pergunta é bem diferente. http://wiki.c2.com/?JavaScriptSucks e https://hackernoon.com/how-it-feels-to-learn-javascript-in-2016-d3a717dd577f e https://whydoesitsuck.com/why-does-javascript-suck/ e o fato da maioria dos programadores JS não fazerem noção do que estão fazendo em algo que expõe segurança.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode colocar o código dentro do eval.

```
eval('var teste = ' + object );
```

Comment: Olá @DenilsonOliveira muito obrigado pela disposição em ajudar. Bem, o problema da sua resposta é que o meu objeto do qual quero obter no js é um objeto C# e estou tentando fazer o Razor "conversar" adequadamente com o js. Além disso, no final da pergunta, enumerei alguns pontos que gostaria que fossem tratados na resposta.