# String com nome de Função em JS

Tags: javascript

Em `javascript`, como faço para pegar o valor de uma `string` e usar como chamanda de uma função, guardo no banco de dados qual a função usar no `onchange` de um input, exe: `validaData`, `validaCPF`, `diaUtil`.

Exemplo:

```
var func = "processaDados";
func("teste",2);

function processaDados(x,y){
    alert(x);
}
```

ja vi isso em `php` se não me engano.

Answer (score 8):

A referência da função fica disponível no objeto `window` através da chave igual ao nome da função. Ou seja, para chamar a função, basta fazer:

```
const f = window[func];

f("parametro");
```

Veja um exemplo:

```js
function foo(text) {
   console.log(text);
}

const func = "foo";
const f = window[func];

f("Hello World");
```

Ou pode fazer diretamente a chamada:

```
window[func]("parametro");
```

Veja:

```js
function foo(text) {
  console.log(text);
}

const func = "foo";

window[func]("Hello World");
```

Comment: Essa resposta merece muitos votos positivos por explicar muito bem como resolver o problema sem recorrer a `evil`, digo, `eval`.

Comment: @Renan qual o problema do eval?

Comment: @LuizSantos Essas podem ser uma leituras interessantes: 1. [Eval é mocinho ou bandido?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/128845/5878) 2. [Uso do eval() em javascript: quais os prós e contras?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4154/5878)

Comment: @LuizSantos a primeira pergunta indicada pelo Anderson tem uma resposta minha.

Answer (score 4):

Eu evitaria o uso de `eval()`. Você pode guardar suas funções num objeto (não array, como dito originalmente) de funções e depois chamar passando como chave o nome da função que você quer, assim:

```js
funcoes = {
  soma: function() {

    console.log("chamou a função soma");

  }
}

var funcao = "soma";

funcoes[funcao]();
```

Comment: +1 pela ideia, mas isso que você fez é um objeto, não um Array.

Comment: E pra quem deu o voto negativo: essa ideia é tão boa quanto a melhor votada até agora. Se fosse mais elaborada poderia até ser a melhor resposta. É mais organizado e funciona em ambientes além do navegador (i.e.: Node.js). Pensem nisso antes de dar um voto negativo.

Comment: Realmente é um objeto, obrigado pela correção.

Answer (score -1):

Pode-se utilizar `eval()`, apesar de não recomendado por questões de segurança.

Segundo a [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval):

> O método eval() avalia código JavaScript representado como uma string.

Com o seu exemplo:

```js
var func = eval("processaDados");
func("teste",2);
    
function processaDados(x,y){
    console.log(x);
}
```