# Dirty Checking AngularJS e VueJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, vue.js

Eu gosto muito do *AngularJS*, e quando li em artigos sobre seu descontinuamento, era que um dos principais motivos se dava pelo *Dirty Checking*. Penso eu que *Dirty Checking* são as verificações feitas pelo Two way data binding, queria saber se o *VueJS* possui esse Dirty Checking, porque eu leigo vendo por fora, não vejo a diferença entre os dois códigos. Para mim os dois são *two way data binding*

**Usando VueJS**

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
  teste: "Teste"
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/vue/1.0.16/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <input v-model="teste">
  {{teste}}
</div>
```

**Usando AngularJS**

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.teste = 'Teste';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <input ng-model="teste">
  <p>{{ teste }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Boa pergunta! Depois das publicações que eu vi hoje aqui no site, queria poder upar essa aqui umas 20 vezes.

Comment: Desculpe, não domino AngularJs, mas aonde leu sobre ele ser *descontinuado*? Quero dizer, acho que leu de algum lugar que possivelmente tenha alguma informação errada. Não que eles não promovam o Angular (sem JS), mas creio que o AngularJS ainda recebe melhorias, mas seria interessante se você posta-se de onde obteve essa informação.

Comment: Creio que `AngularJS` é a versão 1. A semana passada saiu o Angular 5.

Comment: `AngularJS` é uma coisa. `Angular` é outra. O `AngularJS` é chamado de `Angular 1` porque foi a primeira versão, mas para não confundir, o pessoal da **Google** separou o `AngularJS` e `Angular`. O `Angular` **(Que já esta na sua versão 5)**, é um framework re-escrito do zero, ele tem conceitos totalmente diferentes do `AngularJS`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que conheço de Angular o `ng-model` e o `v-model` são a mesma ideia. Uma pesquisa rápida confirmou isso.

Hoje em dia fala-se muito de *unidirectional data binding*, o que quer dizer que o state/mutações de dados devem acontecer numa só direção, num fluxo de A para B. Em particular: do detentor desse *state* (a Store, o `data` ou `computed` no Vue/Vuex).

Esta ideia/regra é útil, mas existem exepções que vale a pena considerar, assim como o [`eval`](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/27688/129) pode ser útil algures. Esta é uma delas.

O `v-model` permite que o `this.teste` do componente seja mudado quando o `input` mudar, e permite o `input` ser mudado quando o `this.teste` mudar. Isso pode gerar bugs, porque o Vue reage a essas mudanças, e ser difícil de "debugar".

Ainda assim, o `v-model` não é obrigatório. É perfeitamente possivel fazer um ciclo fechado de *state* para evitar o v-model. Um exemplo minimalista seria:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    value: ''
  },
  watch: {
    value(val) {
      console.log('Novo value!', val);
    }
  },
  methods: {
    updateValue(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      this.value = e.target.value;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.3/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="text" :value="value" @input="updateValue" placeholder="Escreve aqui...">
  <p>{{value}}</p>
</div>
```

Porém, eu acho que é prático, e limitado a casos específicos, é útil.

A mesma ideia com `v-modal`:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    value: ''
  },
  watch: {
    value(val) {
      console.log('Novo value!', val);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.3/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input type="text" v-model="value" placeholder="Escreve aqui...">
  <p>{{value}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Gostei da resposta! Mas ainda não me deixou muito claro... Como você disse, `v-model` e `ng-model` são muito parecidos. E de facto, são! Mas Porque em tanto lugar diz que `ng-model` fazia um Dirt Cheking ruim, e o `v-model` não? O que o `AngularJS` tinha de tão ruim no seu *two way data binding* comparado ao `VueJS`?

Comment: @Jackson não conheço o código interno do Angular mas pelo que li ele faz dirty checking quando vai buscar o valor dos elementos que usam esse `ng-model`. E lendo [este comentário do criados do Vue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/96#issuecomment-35052704) que trabalhava no Google e conhece bem Angular o Vue não usa dirty checking.

Comment: Interessante! Pelo que li o Vue não usa o `Dirty Cheking`, e sim `Observable pattern`. Dei uma lida nessa pergunta que achei super interessante! Vale a leitura: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24698620/dirty-checking-on-angular