# Mudança de string para operador aritmético

Tags: javascript

Existe alguma forma de deixar o código abaixo mais dinâmico, tipo ao escolher o `switch` desejado ele já fazer a tabuada?

```
var num = parseFloat(prompt('Digite um numero'))
var sinalTabuada = prompt('Digite o sinal que desejar descobrir a tabuada')
var indice = 1;

 switch(sinalTabuada){
    case '+':
        while(indice <= 10){
            document.write('a soma de ' + num + sinalTabuada + indice + ' = ' + (num 'sinalTabuada' indice) + '<br>'); // transformar o sinalTabuada em operador aritimetico mesmo..
        indice++;
        }
    break;
```

Comment: Talvez o [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval) seja o que vc procura. Só recomendo que antes leia [isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/128845/112052) e [isso](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4154/112052)

Comment: Outra dica - não diretamente relacionada - é dar nomes mais significativos para as variáveis. `sinalTabuada` implica em multiplicação, mas se o sinal pode receber qualquer operação, talvez o nome da variável devesse ser `sinal`, `operacao`, `sinalOperacao`, ou algo assim. O mesmo para a mensagem, que diz "A soma de...", mas na verdade nem sempre será a soma. Podem parecer detalhes bobos, mas nomes e mensagens melhores [ajudam na hora de programar e entender o que está fazendo/acontecendo](https://hackernoon.com/the-art-of-naming-variables-52f44de00aad).

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda e as dicas!

Answer (score 2):

Como o colega @hkotsubo comentou, você pode utilizar o `eval` para resolver seu problema. Fiz um exemplo para te ajudar:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Tabuada</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      const numero = parseFloat(prompt("Digite um numero"));
      const sinal = prompt("Digite o sinal que desejar descobrir a tabuada");
      let valor = 1;

      if (sinal === "+" || sinal === "-" || sinal === "/" || sinal === "*") {
        while (valor <= 10) {
          document.write(
            `A soma de ${numero} ${sinal} ${valor} = ${eval(
              numero + sinal + valor
            )} <br/>`
          );
          valor++;
        }
      } else {
        console.error("Sinal inválido.");
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Espero ter ajudado! '-'

Comment: Ajudou bastante, abriu a minha mente! Obrigado!